# Show that the closure operation has the following properties

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, real-numbers

Let $E_1$ and $E_2$ be subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. I need to show that the closure operation has the following properties:

 a)$(E_1 \subset E_2) \Rightarrow (closure(E_1) \subset closure(E_2))$ 
 b)$closure(E_1 \cup E_2) = closure(E_1) \cup closure(E_2)$
 c)$closure(E_1 \cap E_2) \subset closure(E_1) \cap closure(E_2)$ 
For a) I think I figured it out even though I'm not sure if it is the right way to do it: Let $x \in closure(E_1) \Rightarrow x \in E_1 \Rightarrow x \in E_2 \Rightarrow x \in closure(E_2) $ 
 For point b I need to show both the the 'left' inclusion and the 'right' inclusion but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: No, your approach is incorrect. What (equivalent) definitions of closure do you know?

Comment: $$closure(E) = E \cup E^' $$, where $E^'$ is the set of acumulation points of E. Yeah now I realize that my aporoach is not right.

Comment: Do you know that $\bar{E}$ is the smallest closed set containing $E$, in the sense that $\bar{E} = \bigcap \{A:\text{$E\subset A$, $A$ is closed}\}$? If not, try to prove it. This will make everything obvious.

Comment: A sequential approach is natural. A point is in the closure of E if and only if it is the limit of a sequence of points in E. Using this, a) is almost obvious and the hard direction of b) follows from the observation that given any sequence in the union of two sets, there exists at least one subsequence contained in one of the these sets. c) is likewise somewhat trivial if approached sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

a) Suppose $A\subset B$. Now suppose that $a \in \bar{A}$. Then $a$ is the limit of a sequence of terms in $A$ and thus of terms in $B$ and so $a \in \bar{B}$.

b) Note that $A\subset \bar{A}$ and $B\subset \bar{B}$ and so $A\cup B \subset \bar{A}\cup \bar{B}$. But the closure of a set, say $X$, is the smallest closed set containing $X$. So $\overline{A\cup B} \subset \bar{A}\cup \bar{B}$. For the other inclusion, note that $A\subset A\cup B$ and so $\bar{A}\subset \overline{A\cup B}$ and likewise $\bar{B}\subset \overline{A\cup B}$. Hence, $\bar{A}\cup\bar{B} \subset \overline{A\cup B}$.

c) Suppose $x\in \overline{A\cap B}$ then $x$ is the limit of a sequence whose terms lie in $A\cap B$. It follows that $x \in \bar{A}$ and $x\in \bar{B}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answare Dman. For the point a) I think it is not correct. If a belongs to closure(A) that dosen't mean that a  belongs to A. The same approach I've tryied but @Qiyu Wen corrected me. Anyway for the b and c I think thats the way should be done.

Comment: This makes little sense. Unless you are assuming that A is closed (and this isn't one of the assumptions) you can't move from a in the closure of A to a in A

Comment: Whoops, @JohnColeman I was to fast there, I have updated the answer.

Comment: This works, although aesthetically I would prefer a proof which uses the same characterization of closure in all three cases (either all sequential or all in terms of smallest closed set).